# Prove that $\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 0.5x^n ((1 + n) (2 + n))$ for $\mid x\mid<1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis

> Prove that
> $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{2}(1 + n) (2 + n)$$ for $| x|<1$.

To prove this is quite simple. I have taken the second derivate and the geometric series from there by integrating twice. My question is a bit different though. We applied the MVT and therefore we would always have a constant. Apparently we may take $c=0$ all the time but it can be random as well, therefore we would have to add different class of function: linear functions. So we would have to write $c_1x+c_2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 0.5x^n ((1 + n) (2 + n)$ Why can we skip that so easily, of course it cancels out when we take the derivative. I was just curious, thanks in advance!

EDIT: Since we solve that problem locally, namely for $|x| <1$ can you take that concept globally? So for all $x\in I$?

Comment: Take limits as $x \to 0$ and $x \to 1$ to get $c_2=1$ and $c_1=0$.

Comment: My (possible) answer to that is simply that we expand the number of possible functions that might solve the problem.

Comment: (You're missing a factor of $\frac 12$ in the series).

Comment: @Milten thanks, true!

Comment: From this point on "We applied the MVT and therefore we would always have a constant", the meaning is quite mysterious. Please explain.

Comment: Make the Cauchy product of $\sum x^n$ with itself. You get $\frac 1{(1-x)^2}$. And then make this once again.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Since the derivatives are equal the functions lets call them f and g differ only by a constant. To prove that you use the MVT

Comment: Don't you mean the FTC ??

Comment: No!! Mean Value Theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem check implications theorem 2

Comment: Ok, but this corollary is not known as *the* MVT. And your explanations remain barely understandable.

Answer (score 1):

With appropriate convergence conditions,

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\iff\\\iint f(x)\,dx^2=g(x)+c_1x+c_0=a_{-2}+a_{-1}x+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_n}{(n+1)(n+2)}x^{n+2}$$ where $a_{-2},a_{-1}, c_1,c_0$ need not coincide.
So yes, $g$ is indeterminate to a linear term, and this does not matter.